# Identify sentences without a matching word in a list

Tags: python

I have a list of sentences and I want to identify all of them that do not have at least one word in them that match a word contained in another list. I have tried to do this with a list comprehension as

```py
[sentence for sentence in sentences if word_list is not in sentence]
```

which doesn’t work because I’m asking if a word in a word list is not in a sentence.

The key feature I need is to be able to identify all sentences that do not have a word matching a word in the word list. I am looking for ASR errors and I have a list of words, at least one of which must be in each sentence or that sentence had an ASR error.

I can figure out how to do this with `grep -v` and piping them all together but I would like to do this in Python.

Comment: `[sentence for sentence in sentences if not any([word in sentence for word in word_list])]`

Comment: @mamun that should be posted as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to identify sentence that doesn't contain any word in the word_list, use the following one liner:

```
In [1]: word_list = ['USA', 'JAPAN', 'RUSSIA']

In [2]: sentences = ['I went to USA from JAPAN', 'there was no mail', 'I really dont belie
   ...: ve RUSSIA did it']

In [3]: [sentence for sentence in sentences if not any(word in sentence for word in word_
    ...: list)]
Out[3]: ['there was no mail']
```

Comment: Using `any` with a list makes it eager which uses more memory. Move the comprehension directly into the call to `any` so that it stops when the generator yields a single item

Comment: That's a good suggestion to make it greedy, would just using a `generator` do the trick? `[sentence for sentence in sentences if not any(word in sentence for word in word_list)]`

Answer (score 2):

I guess you mean

```
[sentence for sentence in sentences if all(word not in sentence for word in word_list)]
```

As a more general guidance, don't use a comprehension if the logic is more complex than what you can keep in your head at once.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in O(n^2) time complexity.

```
no_match = [sentence for sentence in sentences 
            if [word for word in sentence if word in word_list]]
```

This is equal to:

```
no_match = []
for sentence in sentences:
    words = []
    for word in sentence:
        if word in word_list:
           words.append(word)
    if not words:
        no_match.append(sentence)
```